# How to make a streambuilder return data in other screens

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in Flutter, I have a question about an implementation I want to add my app, I would appreciate your answers, let me know if you need me to give you more information.

I hope, this is clear.

Here is the implementation I want to add my app...

I have a streambuilder in my home page(see below code implementing a container that has a streambuilder as a child) that gets data from firebase(the data is users information) and returns a Listview.builder that builds a list of containers with data like name and email(for each user) in my home screen...now, how can I replace the listView.builder and instead of having those users in a listview.builder, I actually want those users information to be saved one by one into different screens(like creating a user profile for each user).

This is the streambuilder:

```
 Container(
                  ///this is a regular streambuilder as a child of a container
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        ///THIS IS THE LISTVIEW.BUILDER
                        return ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          ///These are some methods that build the containers list with the users information
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              buildItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

COMPLETE CODE FOR MY HOMEPAGE

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/chat_implementation/settings.dart';
import 'chat.dart';
import 'const.dart';
import '../main.dart';


class HomeListViewUsers extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentUserId;

  HomeListViewUsers({Key key, this.currentUserId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => HomeListViewUsersState(currentUserId: currentUserId);
}

class HomeListViewUsersState extends State<HomeListViewUsers> {
  HomeListViewUsersState({Key key, @required this.currentUserId});

  final String currentUserId;
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  bool isLoading = false;
  List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
    const Choice(title: 'Settings', icon: Icons.settings),
    const Choice(title: 'Log out', icon: Icons.exit_to_app),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerNotification();
    configLocalNotification();
  }

  void registerNotification() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

    firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? showNotification(message['notification'])
          : showNotification(message['aps']['alert']);
      return;
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: $message');
      return;
    }, onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
      return;
    });

    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .document(currentUserId)
          .updateData({'pushToken': token});
    }).catchError((err) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.message.toString());
    });
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  void onItemMenuPress(Choice choice) {
    if (choice.title == 'Log out') {
      handleSignOut();
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Settings()));
    }
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'com.dfa.flutterchatdemo'
          : 'com.duytq.flutterchatdemo',
      'Flutter chat demo',
      'your channel description',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);


    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, message['title'].toString(),
        message['body'].toString(), platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: json.encode(message));

  }


  Future<Null> handleSignOut() async {
    this.setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();

    this.setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Chat Screen',
          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            // List
            Container(
              ///here the chats users are called
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    ///THIS IS THE LISTVIEW.BUILDER
                    return ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

                      ///These are some methods that build the containers list with the users information
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          buildItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),

            // Loading
            Positioned(
              child: isLoading
                  ? Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor:
                      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor)),
                ),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              )
                  : Container(),
            )
          ],
        ),
//        onWillPop: onBackPress,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    if (document['id'] == currentUserId) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      return Container(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                child: document['profileImageUrl-'] != null
                    ? CachedNetworkImage(
                  placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      strokeWidth: 1.0,
                      valueColor:
                      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(themeColor),
                    ),
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  ),
                  //i just cange this
                  imageUrl: document['profileImageUrl'],
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )
                    : Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  size: 50.0,
                  color: greyColor,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Name: ${document['nickname']}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'email: ${document['email']}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'About me: ${document['aboutMe'] ?? 'Not available'}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: primaryColor),
                        ),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            ///here is the flat button to go to messages
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Chat(
                  peerId: document.documentID,
                  peerAvatar: document['photoUrl'],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          color: greyColor2,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 10.0, 25.0, 10.0),
          shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      );
    }
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to keep the ListView.builder and have each user be clickable, which would then open a profile screen for them? Or do you not want the ListView.builder at all? If it's the latter, how would you want to access those profile screens?

Comment: That's a good point, yes, I want to keep a listview but just with the functionality of only taking me to the the profile screes that will have the same functionality that it had as a listview but now they will be diferent screens...do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want each item in the ListView.builder to be 'tappable' and send you to a profile screen containing the tapped user's information, try wrapping each ListView element in a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html):

```
    return ListView.builder(
             padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
             itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,                   
             itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
               GestureDetector(
                 onTap: Navigator.push(context, 
                   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile(user_name, user_age, user_etc)),); 
                 child: buildItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index])
               ),
           );
```

You can pass info from your Stream into a newly made UserProfile (or something to that effect) page, which is navigated to by tapping on either of the ListView panels.

Alternatively, in your `buildItem` widget definition, you can return a GestureDetector (which will wrap your current Container) instead and place the `onTap` logic in there.